# Is $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\cong\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, projective-space

Just curious, is it true that $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\cong\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$?

Here I'm writing $\mathbb{A}^1$ is affine space, and $\mathbb{P}^1$ projective space, both over an algebraically closed field, for simplicity.

I know that affine space "behaves well" under taking products, in the sense that $\mathbb{A}^n\times\mathbb{A}^m\cong\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$, but the same is not true for projective space in the sense that $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^m\not\cong\mathbb{P}^{n+m}$. So my gut feeling is that the two are in fact not isomorphic. Is my hunch correct, or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: isomorphic in what sense? As Zariski-topological sets?

Comment: There Picard group is different. So definitely not isomorphic.

Comment: The first is a proper open subset of the second. If the first were even projective then it would have to be a closed subset too, but $(\mathbb{P}^1)^2$ is irreducible...

Comment: Also, the scheme theoretic image of $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1$ is, well, $\mathbb{A}^1$. The image of proper things are proper. $\mathbb{A}^1$ is not proper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A connected projective variety has no non-constant regular functions. But $A^1\times P^1 \to A^1$ is a non-constant regular function.